# Entity Framework bug with table name?

Tags: entity-framework-6.1

I have table **Forums** and entity **Forum**. But when I doing query to this table, Entity Framework generation query to table **Fora**. When in entity class **Forum** add attribute **Table("Forums")** I get proper query. Why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually not a bug, the proper english plural form of Forum is Fora. However, you kind of answered your own questions. You can indeed solve it by adding an attribute Table("Forums").

Source: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forum#English

Comment: And here goes a lesson in english language. Always nice. This is for all never having had that in school (and thus miss what some call a classical education), because FORUM is not an english word, originally - it is latin. And there the plural of the UM singular is A ;) It is also explained in any dictionary - but who uses those these days.

Comment: TomTom I didn't know such a feature of the English language. Next time I check this.